# What $q$ makes this integral $\int _0 ^\infty \frac { \sin (x ^q ) } { x } \, dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I'm asked by the problem what real number $q$ makes the integral

> $$\int _0 ^\infty \frac { \sin (x ^q ) } { x }  \, dx$$

converges.

Using integral by parts I showed that the integral converges for all $q > 0$ (I'm not very sure about my proof). And I think the integral will not converge if $q \le 0 $. But I have trouble showing this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For $q = 0$, it's easy to see that the integral doesn't converge. For $q \neq 0$, you could substitute $u = x^q$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\big(x^q\big)}x~dx~=~\frac\pi{2|q|}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Assume $q>0$.

  Then, by the change of variable $u=x^q$, we have $\log u =q \log x$
  thus $\dfrac{du}u=q\:\dfrac{dx}x$, we find that $$ \int_0^\infty
     \frac{\sin(x^q)}{x}\, dx=\frac1q\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u}\,
     du=\frac1q\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos u}{u^2}\, du $$ where we have
  integrated by parts in the last step, the latter integral **converges**.
- Assume $q<0$.

  Then, by the change of variable $u=x^q$, we have $\log u =q \log x$
  thus $\dfrac{du}u=q\:\dfrac{dx}x$, we find that $$ \int_0^\infty
     \frac{\sin(x^q)}{x}\, dx=-\frac1q\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u}\,
     du=-\frac1q\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos u}{u^2}\, du $$ where we have
  integrated by parts in the last step, the latter integral **converges**.
- Assume $q=0$. Then the inital integral **diverges**.

*Remark*. The two first cases can be handled at the same time.